# Trouble with Bootstrap Card Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I need help with Bootstrap card grid.

I'm trying to make a grid with 6 cards. And I want it to display 2 lines of 3 cards and when the screen is smaller to reduce to 4 lines of 2 etc .. until getting 1 line of 1 when the screen is really small.

My HTML card grid look like that :

```
<div class="services">
        <h2>Serviços</h2>
        <div class="cards">

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fa fa-taxi home_icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3>Atendimento Preferencial</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt home_icons"></i>
            <h3>Agendamentos</h3>
            <p>Aeroportos <br> Guarulhos, Viracopos, Congonhas</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fas fa-hands-helping home_icons"></i>
            <h3>Acompanhamentos</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fas fa-language home_icons"></i>
            <h3>Traduçao</h3>
            <p>Português <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> Francês </p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fas fa-bus home_icons"></i>
            <h3>City Tour / Viagens</h3>
            <p>Interior e Litoral</p>
          </div>

          <div class="card">
            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign home_icons"></i>
            <h3>Transfer a preço fixo</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

And my CSS looks like that :

```
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width:250px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card p {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

// Smallest device
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

It looks like my media queries aren't working. ( I do import my css in the style.css )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUlJ5.jpg

Comment: Can u share expectation image here..? so we can clearify ur problem

Comment: @KiranMistry Since I can't post images. I posted the links

Comment: second link not working i think some error in that

Comment: can u use bootstrap and u told u want single single card in smartphone size correct..?

Comment: Well, I'm using bootstrap. But when I put the @media. It should update when the screen is smaller right ? Well, that's not working. I don't know why ..

Comment: ok....i will post answer if ur issue not resolving then tell me ok... give me 10 to 15 min

Comment: if u satisying with my answer then vote up it will help to other developer

Answer (score 0):

@LovlsGenesis Here is your Solution don't need to use `@media` screen u can use bootstrap class for that

**CSS**

```
.card{
  min-height: 240px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.fa-taxi{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.fa-calendar{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.fa-handshake-o{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.fa-globe{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.fa-bus{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.fa-usd{
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<br>
<h2>Serviços</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-taxi" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3>Atendimento Preferencial</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            <h3>Agendamentos</h3>
            <p>Aeroportos <br> Guarulhos, Viracopos, Congonhas</p>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
            <h3>Acompanhamentos</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <h3>Traduçao</h3>
            <p>Português <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i> Francês </p>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-bus"></i>
            <h3>City Tour / Viagens</h3>
            <p>Interior e Litoral</p>
          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
            <h3>Transfer a preço fixo</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You Can Edit or Preview Code [Here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62b5dxL4/)